# How to alert user if shopping cart is empty? Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website, and whenever there is nothing in the cart, the user should be alerted that there is nothing in the cart, except my coding doesn't seem to respond whatsoever.  How do I fix it so the code will work?

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items').hasChildNodes()){
    alert('Thanks!')
    window.open("payment.html","_self");
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)     
    }
}   
else {
    alert("There is nothing in your cart!");
    }
```

I wanted it to alert "There is nothing in your cart!" but it doesn't alert anything if your cart is empty when clicked.

Comment: Provide html code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasChildNodes` is a function but is being applied to an array. You'll need `[0]` as you have done so when setting the `cartItems` variable.

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0].hasChildNodes()){
  alert('Thanks!')
  // ... other code here
}   
else {
  alert("There is nothing in your cart!");
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-items">
  <div>Shirt</div>
  <div>Trousers</div>
  <div>Socks</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the else statement though, the code before is     document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)        which is connected to a button

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The original code was executing `hasChildNodes()` on an array returned by `getElementsByClassName`. If you add `[0]` as you have done later inside the statement it should work. Try again.